# Can you decrease the size of a library generated with gomobile bind for ios?

Tags: android, ios, go, gomobile

I've been making an Android app with a GoLang library containing my shared code (currently just code for handling an sqlite database) with the intention of making an IOS version in the future using the same library.

Just out of interest I generated an IOS version of my library using `gomobile bind -target=ios -ldflags=-s myproject` and was very surprised to see the resulting framework folder came out at 37mb which may be a deal breaker (this makes a fairly basic app become huge)

My android library generated with `gomobile bind -target=android/arm64 -ldflags=-s myproject` comes in at only 1.7mb (even generating an android library that contains binaries for all architectures comes out at only 7mb)

So my question is, is there some way to reduce the size of the IOS binary? Theres not much info in the gomobile help.

Comment: It's working well on Android sofar. I haven't tried iOS yet

Comment: No worries. The only real limitation is you can't return slices back to java or iOS so you have to get creative and convert your db query results to something supported like a string